# App links don't work from browser

Tags: android, applinks

In my project there are website, android and ios apps. The same link should work for each of this platforms.

For example I want my app to open link `https://workee.co/jobs/?id=5ab11f9ad57f0f19e0d8bf81`.

I have implemented app links as described here: https://developer.android.com/studio/write/app-link-indexing.

I have added `intent-filter` into my `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
            <intent-filter
            android:autoVerify="true"
            tools:targetApi="m">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "https://workee.co/jobs” -->
            <data
                android:host="workee.co"
                android:pathPrefix="/jobs"
                android:scheme="https"/>
        </intent-filter>
```

Then I have upload the `assetlinks.json` file to my site.

All works fine in such apps like Viber and Telegram but when I'm clicking on my link in Chrome and Firefox browsers it doesn't work. It shows me system dialog to select in which app I want to open this link and there is no my app there.  Also it doesn't work in Skype: my link is opened by Skype itself.

**UPD**: I found out that this issue have place only on devices with suites like HTC Sence, OxygenOS, etc. On deveices with pure Android it works correctly.

Comment: As much I learned on this issue throughout is that if the phone has no default browser settled then it let user choose from options i.e. go for installed app or to installed browsers. If we have a browser set as default before or if user opts for option 'browser' instead of app from chooser, the browser only takes user to google play store page to get app installed or opened again.